# Create array from input object data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

//Contact.ts

```
export class Contact {
 name: string;
 lastName: string;
 age: number;
 childrenName: Children[];
 
 constructor(args) {
   if(args) {
     Object.assign(this, args)
   }
 }
}
```

My component receives 4 props objects contacts from parent component

```
export class ChildComponent implements onInit {

  @Input contacts: Contact

  onInit {

    console.log(this.contacts) // List of objects
}
```

How do I create an array from these Objects?

What I've done is, create a arrayContacts = [] property, and than arrayContacts.push(this.contacts).

The problem is that is creating array index 0 for each contact e.g

```
0: contacts {name: "John" ...}                             
0: contacts {name: "Mark" ...}                      
0: contacts {name: "Ben" ...}                             
0: contacts {name: "Lilly" ...}
```

Comment: this contacts: Contact should be array of contacts @Input contacts: Contact[]

Comment: change that Input contacts object to array @Input contacts: Contact[] and send it from parent.